# Grouping a data.frame and filtering based on several conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr, unique

I have a `data.frame` with several columns:

```
df <- data.frame(sgid = c("sg1","sg1","sg2","sg3"), stid = c(NA,"st1",NA,NA), spid = c(NA,NA,NA,"sp3"), sch = c("sch1","sch1","sch2","sch2"), sst = c(11,11,32,21), snd = c(21,21,46,34),
                 qgid = c("qg1","qg1","qg1","qg1"), qtid = c("qt1","qt1","qt1","qt1"), qpid = c("qp1","qp1","qp1","qp1"), qch = c("qch1","qch1","qch1","qch1"), qst = c(111,111,234,21), qnd = c(211,211,267,34))
```

This `data.frame` describes mapping one sequence (i.e. query) onto a database of other sequences (i.e. search).

Search and query sequences are identified by three sets of ids:
`gid`, `tid`, and `pid` (prefixed by s and q for search and query, respectively), and the coordinates of the matches are described by a string: `ch` and two integers: `st` and `nd` (again, prefixed by s and q for search and query, respectively).

`tid` and `pid` are subsets of `gid` in the case of the search, hence in the search database they are kept as separate rows. So, it is possible that the query will 'hit' both `gid` and either `tid` and/or `pid` in different coordinates.

However, as in the case of rows 1 and 2 in `df`, the query is hitting the search inside the `tid` and hence the search and query coordinates of rows 1 and 2 are identical.

So I'm looking for is a `function` (probably through `dplyr::group` and `dplyr::filter`) that will return a unique `df` based on the definition above.

This is my crude way of achieving this:

```
tmp.df <- df %>% dplyr::select(-stid,-spid) %>% unique()

uniq.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(tmp.df),function(i){
  tmp.df.i <- tmp.df[i,,drop=F] %>% dplyr::left_join(df)
  if(!(all(is.na(tmp.df.i$stid) & is.na(tmp.df.i$spid)))){
    tmp.df.i <- tmp.df.i[which(!is.na(tmp.df.i$stid) | !is.na(tmp.df.i$spid)),,drop=F]
  } else{
    tmp.df.i <- tmp.df.i %>%
      dplyr::select(-stid,-spid) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(stid=NA,spid=NA)
  }
  return(tmp.df.i)
}))

#organize the columns of uniq.df to the order of df:
uniq.df <- uniq.df %>% dplyr::select_(.dots = colnames(df))

> uniq.df
   sgid stid spid  sch sst snd qgid qtid qpid  qch qst qnd
2   sg1  st1 <NA> sch1  11  21  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 111 211
1   sg2 <NA> <NA> sch2  32  46  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 234 267
11  sg3 <NA>  sp3 sch2  21  34  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1  21  34
```

Looking for something more elegant.

Comment: Just edited my post accordingly

Comment: Based on Wimpel's answer do you need `df[!duplicated(df[setdiff(names(df), c("stid","spid"))]), ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` solution

**sample data**

```
#    sgid stid spid  sch sst snd qgid qtid qpid  qch qst qnd
# 1:  sg1 <NA> <NA> sch1  11  21  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 111 211
# 2:  sg1  st1 <NA> sch1  11  21  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 111 211
# 3:  sg2 <NA> <NA> sch2  32  46  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 234 267
# 4:  sg3 <NA>  sp3 sch2  21  34  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1  21  34
```

**code**

```
library( data.table )
setDT( df )
#get columns you wish to exclude from duplication-check
cols <- c( "stid", "spid" )
#keep non-duplicated rows, based on a subset of df (without the columns in `cols`)
df[ !duplicated( df[, !..cols] ), ][]

#    sgid stid spid  sch sst snd qgid qtid qpid  qch qst qnd
# 1:  sg1 <NA> <NA> sch1  11  21  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 111 211
# 2:  sg2 <NA> <NA> sch2  32  46  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 234 267
# 3:  sg3 <NA>  sp3 sch2  21  34  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1  21  34
```

**alternative**
if you do not wish to keep the first row of a duplicate, but the last, use:

```
df[ !duplicated( df[, !..cols], fromLast = TRUE ), ][]  #<-- note fromlast-argument!

#    sgid stid spid  sch sst snd qgid qtid qpid  qch qst qnd
# 1:  sg1  st1 <NA> sch1  11  21  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 111 211
# 2:  sg2 <NA> <NA> sch2  32  46  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1 234 267
# 3:  sg3 <NA>  sp3 sch2  21  34  qg1  qt1  qp1 qch1  21  34
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this with `dplyr`:

```
cols <- setdiff(names(df), c("stid", "spid"))

df %>% group_by_at(cols) %>% 
  summarise(stid = ifelse(length(unique(stid)) == 1,
                          unique(stid), 
                          unique(stid)[! is.na(unique(stid))]),
            spid = ifelse(length(unique(spid)) == 1,
                          unique(spid), 
                          unique(spid)[! is.na(unique(spid))]))
```

Or you can use the function `Coalesce` from the package `DescTools` (or even define you own function to select the first non NA value):

```
df %>% group_by_at(cols) %>% 
  summarise(stid = DescTools::Coalesce(stid),
            spid = DescTools::Coalesce(spid))
```